# issue with flow layout panel / link labels

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel, linklabel

i am setting text to a link label and adding these labels to a flow layout panel. It seems to be chopping off the ends of the link labels and as such i have labels with only 3/4's of the text. Does anyone know why this might be?

Thanks

Comment: I can think of many things that could cause this... Can you give us some more details? That would be much easier than typing out an exhaustive list.

Comment: Please post code - I think you've probably got the width set too thin!

Comment: Not to sure what details i can add! Though you were the person who helped me the other day ;). it seems as if it only types 16 charachters. It displays the link labels in 2 columns

Comment: code isnt possible as its sensative work data, im just setting a link label to a value and then adding this to a flow layout, which is a panel inside a table layout

Comment: @tom: Mostly, I'm thinking about whatever properties you've set on either the `FlowLayoutPanel` control or the `LinkLabel` controls. They'd show up as **bold** in the Properties Window, and wouldn't contain any sensitive information. This is one of those things you could make happen easily with a design-time setting like `Padding` or `Margin`.

Comment: everything to do with the layout is standard, the only things in bold are autocompletecustomsource set to collection, size (changing makes no dsifference) location, multiline = true, scroll bar = vertical, abd lines as string[] array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are adding the LinkLabels to the FlowLayoutPanel through code, but there is a property you can set to make them work properly.

```
    var link = new LinkLabel();
    link.Text = "Some really long string";
    link.AutoSize = true;   //This is really important!

    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(link);
```

If you don't set each LinkLabels AutoSize property, they just chop off any text that goes further than their default bounds.

**Edit:**
My Testapp consists of placing a FlowLayoutPanel on the form, and a button to click, with the above code in the OnClick handler.  Nothing else was changed on the form.

Without the AutoSize property set to true, I had the same problem you described.  Setting it to True fixes it for me at least :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this by dropping a FlowLayoutPanel on a blank form and dropping in many LinkLabels. The width of the FlowLayoutPanel is narrow and I have tried adding Text properties to the link labels to break the layout.

Even putting text with no spaces in the link label doesn't cause the issue you describe - the text simply wraps around onto the next line.

Do you have any properties set on the link labels? This is the only way I could get this issue to occur.

I changed the size of one of the link labels to a fixed size smaller than the text and this pretty much did exactly what you report. I would suggest that the Width property of your link label is smaller than the text you are displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the `LinkArea` property of the link label .. the default is about 25.
I think you will have to set it to the maximum value you are using to display as text for the link label.